# Select, Sum, Average per day - multi values from same table - can it be done?

Tags: mysql, sum, distinct

I have a table collect temp, etc. for my wife (farmer)
Now we start to have some data in the table and it would be nice to get a graph on this.

Table structure

id, timestamp (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), temp_c, feelslike_c, humidity, PM10, gbdefraindex

We collect data min. 1 time/hour, and i need help to sum up this for average values for each day
I could take it out each day and put it in to a new table, but there must be some nice SQL Q to get data out from "main table" at once?

temp_c, feelslike_c, humidity, PM10, gbdefraindex is the values i need, is it possible to do this in ONE Q, or should i write one for each?

For our part of the world, it would be nice to show the village PM10 values next year so they don't burn so much in fields as well :) .

I not been try anything, since i'm not sure how to start thinking. If it was one value, then its ok for me, but now its 5 values to handle.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, perhaps this will assist:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
  temp_c FLOAT NOT NULL,
  feelslike_c FLOAT NOT NULL,
  humidity FLOAT NOT NULL,
  PM10 FLOAT NOT NULL,
  gbdefraindex FLOAT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO your_table (timestamp, temp_c, feelslike_c, humidity, PM10, gbdefraindex)
VALUES ('2023-04-20 12:00:00', 20.5, 21.2, 60.3, 15.2, 2.5),
       ('2023-04-20 13:00:00', 21.2, 22.1, 58.7, 16.5, 3.1),
       ('2023-04-21 12:00:00', 19.8, 20.5, 62.1, 14.8, 2.1),
       ('2023-04-21 13:00:00', 20.1, 21.0, 61.5, 15.1, 2.3);
```

> ```
> Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS date,
       ROUND(AVG(temp_c),2) AS avg_temp_c,
       ROUND(AVG(feelslike_c),2) AS avg_feelslike_c,
       ROUND(AVG(humidity),2) AS avg_humidity,
       ROUND(AVG(PM10),2) AS avg_PM10,
       ROUND(AVG(gbdefraindex),2) AS avg_gbdefraindex
FROM your_table
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp);
```

| date | avg_temp_c | avg_feelslike_c | avg_humidity | avg_PM10 | avg_gbdefraindex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-20 | 20.85 | 21.65 | 59.5 | 15.85 | 2.8 |
| 2023-04-21 | 19.95 | 20.75 | 61.8 | 14.95 | 2.2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f8hJjBW9)

1. The DATE function is applied to the timestamp column, which extracts only the date portion of the timestamp. This creates a new column called date.
2. The AVG function is used to calculate the average values of temperature, feelslike temperature, humidity, PM10, and gbdefraindex (for each "group" which here is one day).
3. The ROUND function is used to round the average values to two decimal places.
4. The results are grouped by the date column using the GROUP BY clause (causing each date to be one row).

The result shows average values of the specified columns for each day.

Comment: Paul - Thanks you so much for take time to not only show, but also explain :) 
It worked perfect and now i can take this in to a chart 

You learn something every day :)